# When opening new terminal instance, getting fatal error: MSpanList_Insert error

Tags: macos, terminal

Whenever I open a new terminal instance, I get the following error:

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x44a3000 0x5859f1fae0a 0x0 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x42046b0, 0x10)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:530 +0x90 fp=0x7ffeefbfec30 sp=0x7ffeefbfec18
runtime.(*mSpanList).insert(0x42e3948, 0x44a3000)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:933 +0x293 fp=0x7ffeefbfec60 sp=0x7ffeefbfec30
runtime.(*mheap).freeSpanLocked(0x42e3140, 0x44a3000, 0x100, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:809 +0x4be fp=0x7ffeefbfecc8 sp=0x7ffeefbfec60
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x42e3140, 0x8, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:675 +0x2a0 fp=0x7ffeefbfed20 sp=0x7ffeefbfecc8
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x42e3140, 0x1, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:553 +0x4e3 fp=0x7ffeefbfed78 sp=0x7ffeefbfed20
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x42e3140, 0x1, 0x15, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:437 +0x119 fp=0x7ffeefbfeda8 sp=0x7ffeefbfed78
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:502 +0x41 fp=0x7ffeefbfedd8 sp=0x7ffeefbfeda8
runtime.systemstack(0x7ffeefbfedf8)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:307 +0xab fp=0x7ffeefbfede0 sp=0x7ffeefbfedd8
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x42e3140, 0x1, 0x10000000015, 0x402770f)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mheap.go:503 +0x63 fp=0x7ffeefbfee28 sp=0x7ffeefbfede0
runtime.(*mcentral).grow(0x42e4d40, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mcentral.go:209 +0x93 fp=0x7ffeefbfee90 sp=0x7ffeefbfee28
runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0x42e4d40, 0x42df478)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mcentral.go:89 +0x47d fp=0x7ffeefbfeed0 sp=0x7ffeefbfee90
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x449f000, 0x15, 0x7ffeefbfef38)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/mcache.go:119 +0xcc fp=0x7ffeefbfef08 sp=0x7ffeefbfeed0
runtime.mallocgc.func2()
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:642 +0x2b fp=0x7ffeefbfef28 sp=0x7ffeefbfef08
runtime.systemstack(0x7ffeefbfefc8)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:307 +0xab fp=0x7ffeefbfef30 sp=0x7ffeefbfef28
runtime.mallocgc(0x180, 0x41de0e0, 0x0, 0x800000000)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:643 +0x869 fp=0x7ffeefbff008 sp=0x7ffeefbfef30
runtime.newobject(0x41de0e0, 0x42df7d0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/malloc.go:781 +0x42 fp=0x7ffeefbff030 sp=0x7ffeefbff008
runtime.malg(0x8000, 0x42dfa40)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:2634 +0x27 fp=0x7ffeefbff068 sp=0x7ffeefbff030
runtime.mpreinit(0x42dfd80)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/os1_darwin.go:140 +0x1f fp=0x7ffeefbff080 sp=0x7ffeefbff068
runtime.mcommoninit(0x42dfd80)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:494 +0x105 fp=0x7ffeefbff0c8 sp=0x7ffeefbff080
runtime.schedinit()
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:434 +0x79 fp=0x7ffeefbff110 sp=0x7ffeefbff0c8
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ffeefbff158, 0x3, 0x7ffeefbff158, 0x0, 0x7fff4f604145, 0x7fff4f604145, 0x0, 0x3, 0x7ffeefbff3b8, 0x7ffeefbff3bf, ...)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:138 +0x132 fp=0x7ffeefbff118 sp=0x7ffeefbff110
```

I have googled this many times unsuccessfully. I've seen other folks say it's an old version of go installed with Brew, but I don't have Go installed

```
➜ brew list
ack                             glib                            libmpc@0.8                      pinentry
apple-gcc42                     gmp                             libogg                          pixman
autoconf                        gmp4                            libpng                          pkg-config
automake                        gmp@4                           libtiff                         postgresql
boost                           gnupg                           libtool                         ppl011
cairo                           gnupg2                          libusb                          ppl@0.11
cloog-ppl015                    gobject-introspection           libusb-compat                   pth
cloog@0.15                      gpg-agent                       libvorbis                       python
cmake                           harfbuzz                        libvpx                          qt
colordiff                       heroku                          libxml2                         rbenv
curl                            highlight                       libxslt                         readline
direnv                          icu4c                           libyaml                         reattach-to-user-namespace
dirmngr                         ilmbase                         little-cms2                     redis
eigen                           imagemagick                     llvm35                          ruby-build
elasticsearch                   isl                             lua                             scons
ffmpeg                          jbig2dec                        makedepend                      sqlite
fontconfig                      jpeg                            memcached                       texi2html
freerdp                         lame                            mongodb                         tmux
freetype                        libass                          mpfr                            watch
fribidi                         libassuan                       mpfr2                           watchman
gcc                             libevent                        mpfr@2                          wget
gcc46                           libffi                          mysql                           x264
gcc@4.6                         libgcrypt                       node                            xvid
gdbm                            libgpg-error                    numpy                           xz
gettext                         libiconv                        opencv                          yarn
ghostscript                     libksba                         openexr                         yasm
giflossy                        libmemcached                    openssl
gifsicle                        libmpc                          pcre
git                             libmpc08                        phantomjs
```

Others said something might have been compiled with an older version of Go. If this is what's happening, how might I go about figuring out what library that is?

I've researched this so many times and always end up just ignoring it. I'd really love to figure out the root issue!

**Update**

Someone suggested I update all my brew dependencies. I ran `brew upgrade` and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to macOS 10.13.4, ran `brew upgrade`, and this exact problem was finally resolved.

I previously ran `brew doctor` and followed the recommendations as well as `brew cleanup` and `brew upgrade` to no avail. I also installed Go and uninstalled it, though it wasn't installed to begin with.

Answer (score -2):

Just to note that I have been struggling with this with a Git commands since upgrading my mac to High Sierra. Having already tried installing a later version of Go (which I also had not installed previously), running `brew upgrade` did finally fix the problem for me.